# Liquibase change log precondition

Tags: mysql, grails, liquibase, changeset, changelog

I need to create a changelog precondition so that I can halt my changelog and the start up of my grails app if it fails.

The conditions I need to cater for are below in the table but I have had no luck implementing such a precondition.

My current attempt is here

`<preConditions onFail="HALT" onFailMessage="Version cannot be installed, please install an earlier version.">
   <not>
     <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">select count(*) from someTable WHERE id = 'someId'</sqlCheck>
   </not>
   <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">select count(*) from someTable</sqlCheck>
 </preConditions>`

```
Table populated | Row exists | Action
        Y       |       Y    | Run change log
        X       |       X    | Run change log
        Y       |       X    | Don't run
        X       |       X    | Run change log
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use grails preconditions to cater for the different scenarios
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/2.0.x/index.html#groovyPreconditions